# Set focus to the first widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a dialog with tabs, and each tab has some check blocks and input blocks.

I think if I do not set any focus order, the order is defined in terms of the order in which those widgets are added. I am fine with the initial order.

After users tab and change focus, I wanted to reset the focus back to the first widget. Because the widget tree is constructed top-down in my case, I think I can traverse children of each widget node to find the first widget.

Is there a better way to do? Will children be stored in the order they are added?

Comment: When exactly do you want to return the focus back? Do you know the exact widget you want to give focus to or no, just relying on whatever it is? Do you want to return the focus whenever user pressed tab? So nothing else will receive focus?

Comment: I think I know which widget should have focus. If so, I may want to simply set focus of that widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`QWidget::nextInFocusChain`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nextInFocusChain) method to retrieve the first widget that must receive the focus.

Comment: I think the API tells us only what the next focus will be, but we cannot know who is the first focus originally?

Comment: As far as I know, you are right, you must have some prior information about it. I've used this method when switching to UIs generated from DBs, so I don't know the first widget but I do know the previous one (a 'save' button, or something like it).